# Fastest and efficient way to update mysql data

Tags: mysql, database, scalability

I have 2 db tables:

Tbl1:

- user_id
- item_id
- qty
- date_purchase

Tbl2 (summary of table 1):

- user_id
- item_id
- number_of_qty_purchased
- last_purchase

For now I have only a few thousands of Tbl1. My concern is the scalability of my current approach (retrieve and manually loop on program level, then update the Tbl2) What is the best way to update Tbl2?

Best regards.

Comment: I'm not sure you even need the second table.  Why do you think you need it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need table 2 at all.

You can determine what you're after from table 2 by querying table 1.

- Number purchased of any item:

Select sum(qty) from table_1 where item_id = [id of your item] and user_id = [id of your user];

- Last purchased date of given item for given user

select max(date_purchase) from table_1 where item_id = [id of your item] and user_id = [id of your user];

Also, remember to add indexes to table 1 so that your querying is as fast as possible.